# Crackling and delayed sound after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04

I just upgraded to 22.04, and I noticed that the sound on my laptop is crackling. Software update didn't help but I noticed that this happens when I attach second monitor. I do it via hdmi and choose join displays option

Comment: for cracking sounds,  you might want to toggle off the Over-Amplification in the Sound setting. As for software update, what did you update that you think should have improved the problems?

Comment: I have Over-Amplification turned off. Updated some general stuff via Software Updater, that what was set by default I don't know what exactly. Now I have notification "The software on this computer is up to date"

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, but only with bluetooth headphones, not HDMI output or normal speaker. Disabling over amplification didn't fix it.